# PHP упростить код

Tags: php

Есть следующий код:

```
public static function all()
{
    $posts_array = [];
    for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) { 
        $posts_array[] = new Post('title', 'url', 'description', 'text');   
    }
    return $posts_array;
}
```

Интересует, как можно вернуть сразу несколько `Post`, без использования переменной.
Пробовал так:

```
public static function all()
{
    for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) { 
        return new Post('title', 'url', 'description', 'text');   
    }
}
```

Но в таком случае возвращается только один элемент.

Comment: в данном случае никак

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.generators.syntax.php

Comment: вы серьезно тут считаете. что наличие `$posts_array` как-то упрощает, или усложняет код?

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны понимать, что ключевое слово return выходит из цикла на первой же итерации. ИМХО ответ на вопрос - никак.  Вы можете вернуть какую-либо  совокупность объектов типа массива  . Либо же использовать класс итератор с next() . Php учил лет 10 назад , поэтому точно не помню. Короче управлять можно итерациями , получил объект, хочешь второй написал hasnext() и next() типа такого. Почитайте в оф. Документации про итераторы и генераторы, может вам это нужно

Comment: Вопрос в том, как потом он использовать это  будет. Если передавать массив в шаблон (что скорее всего) - то смысла от генератора будет нулевой